# Problems with GIDSignInDelegate, can't conform it despite sign functions have been added

Tags: swift, google-signin

I get stuck with GIDSignInDelegate, can't conform it despite sign functions have been added as in the Image included.

[stuck with GIDSignInDelegate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG7TL.png)

Comment: import GoogleSignIn

Comment: I already did everything in official document [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that...  Double-click on the red symbol to let Xcode add missing delegate methods.

Comment: Fixed, my xcode require Swift.Error, not Error in the sign function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because libraries are constantly updated all the time, and documentation often not.
Method may change a bit and delegate need to conform to current one, just click on red symbol/dot hit fix and xcode will implement necessary methods for you, don't forget to delete duplicated, they will look almost the same most of the times.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed, my xcode requires **Swift.Error!**, not **Error!**

```
extension LogInVC: GIDSignInDelegate {
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: **Swift.Error!**) {}

not this one

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: **Error!**) {}

}
```